# Don’t show the “This edit was already approved/rejected” message; it is irrelevant

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When I approve or reject an edit suggestion, that edit suggestion disappears from the page. That’s really nice because that way I can go through them until the page is empty.

Unfortunately, edit suggestions that have *already* been approved/rejected stick around on the page, telling me that it’s already been approved/rejected. I don’t really understand the use in that. Just don’t care about it and disappear the edit suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, edit suggestions that you approve or reject are now being  *collapsed* into a one-line summary at the top of the page, rather than hidden altogether. That way, you can still click on the link to get more information about who was responsible for approving/rejecting it. I like that system much better than what we used to have, and I think we ought to keep it.

Likewise, instead of causing edit suggestions that have already been approved/rejected to "disappear",
I think a better idea would be to collapse them in the same way. That would still keep them from cluttering up the screen, but it would also allow those who are curious to click and find out more information or add further edits of their own.